# How to merge the '--' records with 'non--' records using plsql or sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

[Please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZucS3.png)

## ID  SEQNO   DATE    TEXT

```
CD1 1   12/1/2015   HELLO HO    
CD1 2   12/1/2015    --W ARE YOU    
CD1 3   12/1/2015    --? received an account recovery   
CD1 4   12/1/2015    --request on   
CD1 5   12/1/2015    -- Stack   
CD1 6   12/1/2015    -- Overflow.   
CD1 7   12/2/2015   This email address is   
CD1 8   12/2/2015    ---associated with 
CD1 9   12/2/2015    --an account, but  
CD1 10  12/2/2015    ---no password is associated.  
CD1 11  12/3/2015   As a reminder, you  
CD1 12  12/3/2015    --can use any of the following credentials.    
CD1 13  12/3/2015   once logged in, you can review existing credentials.    
CD1 14  12/3/2015   If you did not initiate this account recovery reque 
CD1 15  12/3/2015    --st, just ignore this email   
Required Answer:                
ID  SEQNO   DATE    TEXT    
CD1 1   12/1/2015   HELLO HOW ARE YOU.? received an account recovery request on StackOverflow.  
CD1 7   12/2/2015   This email address is associated with an account, but no password is associated.    
CD1 11  12/3/2015   As a reminder, you can use any of the following credentials.    
CD1 13  12/3/2015   once logged in, you can review existing credentials.    
CD1 14  12/3/2015   If you did not initiate this account recovery request, just ignore this email
```

Code ? Can you please help me in merge the '--' records with 'non--' records using plsql or sql?

Comment: What have you tried? Off the top of my head, I'd first group the rows (probably by using something like the `last_value(case when text like ' --%' then null else seq_no end ignore nulls)` analytic function) to obtain a group number and then doing a listagg on the resultant rows, based on the previously derived group number. Give it a go yourself and if you get stuck, we'll be happy to help you.

Comment: I tried listagg and wm_concat but the thing is 12/3/2015 date all records are combining into one record.

Comment: CD1 11  12/3/2015   As a reminder, you can use any of the following credentials.    once logged in, you can review existing credentials.    If you did not initiate this account recovery request, just ignore this email

Comment: Siyual: Thanks for your suggestion L.as

Comment: Boneist : I really appreciate your help Thanks Boneist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not obvious how to do this.  You need to identify the groups.  One way is to assign to each row the number of non `--` rows before it.  You can do this with a cumulative sum.  That gives the information you need for aggregation:

```
select id, min(seqno) as seqno, min(date) as date,
       listagg((case when text like '--' then substr(text, 3)
                     else text
                end), ' ') within group (order by seqno)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when text not like '--%' then 1 else 0 end) over
                 (order by id, seqno) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp, id;
```

Comment: Gordon Linoff Thank you very much i have been trying this for 2days you did it in 2 min. Thank you Very much once again.